# Can I change the category of registered arXiv papers?

Tags: arxiv

I'd like to change the category of registered arXiv papers as I classified it wrongly.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is of course possible for the people who run arXiv. I guess you tried to do it on your own and failed. The best way in my opinion is to send a message to arXiv and ask for help.

People there do read and answer messages. Technically your request should be easy for them, but it is probably very rare. In principal, there could be some rule explicitly forbidding category changes. But this rule would apply so infrequently that its existence is hard to justify.

Answer (score 3):

You have to open an [appeal](https://arxiv.org/help/moderation/appeals) in order to have your paper reclassified. Note that if the moderators approve your request, it won't be re-announced.